# CMake - copying/merging files with dependencies a change-checking

Tags: cmake

I have a big project with one executable, some plugins and web interface with some generated JSONs.

Therefore, after I compile executables and .so plugins, I'm doing following:

1. Merge all .js files into one big
2. Compile "generators" (set of macros and printfs to describe some structures in C++ code)
3. Run generators and generate JSON files (with some **sed** and **jshon**) processing
4. In install phase, and copy all of this and some other files to their destination directories (which should be created if doesn't exists).

**But** I don't know, how to use CMake to make correct dependencies and date-time checking. Actually, first step is made with:

```
FILE(GLOB WEB_INPUT_JS *.js)
FILE(WRITE scripts.js.tmp "")
FOREACH(SCRIPTFILE ${WEB_INPUT_JS})
    FILE(READ ${SCRIPTFILE} CONTENTS)
    FILE(APPEND scripts.js.tmp "${CONTENTS}")
ENDFOREACH()
CONFIGURE_FILE(scripts.js.tmp ${WEB_BUILD_PATH}/scripts.js COPYONLY)
```

But this doesn't create dependency in makefiles. I want to re-run this piece of "code", when some of `${WEB_INPUT_JS}` files has been changed or `${WEB_BUILD_PATH}/scripts.js` has been deleted.

Third step is made with series of

```
add_custom_command(TARGET gen_somedata POST_BUILD COMMAND gen_somedata | sed ${JSON_SED} | jshon > ${JSON_BUILD_PATH}/somedata.json)
install (FILES ${JSON_BUILD_PATH}/somedata.json ......nextfiles.... DESTINATION ${JSON_OUTPUT_PATH})
```

How is this done? Thanks much for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

So I've finally found out, how to do some of this things.

Merging files is pretty tricky.

First, cmake "script" doing merging is needed (I will explain some lines later). I will name it "concat.cmake":

```
FUNCTION(CONCAT_FILES OUTPUT FILELIST)
    FILE(WRITE ${OUTPUT} "")
    FOREACH(SCRIPTFILE ${FILELIST})
        FILE(READ ${SCRIPTFILE} CONTENTS)
        FILE(APPEND ${OUTPUT} "${CONTENTS}")
    ENDFOREACH() 
ENDFUNCTION(CONCAT_FILES)

STRING(REPLACE "," ";" FILELIST ${FILELIST})
CONCAT_FILES(${OUTPUT} "${FILELIST}")
```

Then, when merging script is used as follows (write it into CMakeLists.txt):

1) First, make an file list (using globbing or by writing file list by hand).

```
FILE(GLOB INPUT_FILES_LIST *.js) # get list of JS files
```

2) The only way, how to pass a cmake list to other cmake script is creating file list separated by comma, then passing comma-separated list to external script. I've done this following way:

```
SET(FILELIST "")
FOREACH(ITEM ${INPUT_FILES_LIST})
    SET(FILELIST "${FILELIST},${ITEM}") # append list item by ','
ENDFOREACH()
STRING(SUBSTRING ${JSFILES} 1 -1 JSFILES) # remove first ','
```

3) Now it's not problem to call merging script..

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT some_output_file.ext
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DFILELIST=${FILELIST} -DOUTPUT=some_output_frile.ext -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/concat.cmake
    DEPENDS ${INPUT_FILES_LIST} VERBATIM )
```

The precedent code will correctly track changes in input files and output file will be generated when missing or input changes. Installation is just easy as 
    INSTALL (FILES "output.ext" DESTINATION /usr/share/...)